# turn on and off chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a chrome extension ,this extension have 2 icons in the browser action (On & Off) ;
basically when it is On the background execute the script.js (Inject the file:script.js)
using the `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"script.js",function(){});`

I had problems to turn it off !
I have tried to use messages communication between the background.js and the script.js but this does not work neither .

Comment: What do you mean by turn it on and turn it off?  Do you want the button to entirely disable the extension?  You can't do that and have the "On" button appear -- disabling the extension disables the extension, including the "On" button.

Comment: when it is off, the script wont be able to interact with the tabs.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information.  "I had problems" is not enough -- people will need to see some code, and you will need to explain what you have tried, or they can't help you.

Comment: Communication with a background page does work. Why do you need background anyway? If its to use localStorage, use chrome.storage instead which doesn't need to be done from background.

Comment: @user2997816: Shows us what you have tried and how it failed/what the problem was. Post some code.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your extension should have two states, On and Off. Clicking the extension icon toggles it on/off.

In this case you should use storage so the extension knows what state it is in. So on a click event, use something like:

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('state', function(data) {
      if (data.state === 'on') {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({state: 'off'});
        //do something, removing the script or whatever
      } else {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({state: 'on'});
        //inject your script
      }
    });
  });
```

Note though that this is happening at the extension/browser level and will apply to all tabs, so you may need something more complex that records both the tab ID and the state.

You then have the choice to either always run a content script and check the on/off state before performing some action, or inject and remove the script. I'm not sure if you remove a script though. Depending on what the script does, you may just want to refresh the page (i.e. if your script messes with the DOM and you want to undo that when turning the extension off).

Answer (score 2):

background.js

```
var enable=false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
 enable = enable ? false : true;
 if(enable){
  //turn on...
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'icon.png' });
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'ON' });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); 
 }else{
  //turn off...
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'disable.png'});
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: '' });
 }
});
```

Comment: Fair warning: will fail when using `persistent: false` event pages

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what @david-gilbertson stated for making it active and inactive for certain tabs, I have created that functionality here. I also took added some functions for removing and adding tabs to the array. Enjoy!

```
function addTab(array, new_tab_id)
   {
    array.push(new_tab_id);
    //then call the set to update with modified value
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        active_tabs:array
    }, function() {
        console.log("added tab");
    });
 }

function removeTab(array, rem_tab_id)
{
    const index = array.indexOf(rem_tab_id);
    if (index > -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
    //then call the set to update with modified value
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        active_tabs:array
    }, function() {
        console.log("removed tab");
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {`enter code here`
  chrome.storage.sync.get({active_tabs : []}, function(data) {
      if (data.active_tabs.includes(request.tab_id)) {
        removeTab(data.active_tabs, request.tab_id)
        console.log("Turned Off ".concat(request.tab_id))
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", highlightCurrentHover, false);
      } else {
        addTab(data.active_tabs, request.tab_id)
        console.log("Turned On ".concat(request.tab_id))
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', highlightCurrentHover, false);
      }
    });
);
```